# How to link the jsps in tomcat instead of keeping WEB-INF/jsp folder?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, weblogic

Can anyone please let me know, how to link the jsps in tomcat instead of keeping all jsps in WEB-INF/jsp and binding in the WAR ?
In WEBLOGIC, we can do it by giving the path in weblogic.xml, so everytime we don't need release the WAR for a small jsp fix.

Comment: Look at this article http://www.javadesk.co/server/tomcatJSPFolderLocation.html, I hope it should help you

Answer (score 0):

create tile definition and then just pass tiles name in result of action

eg :

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="test" template="/WEB-INF/views/layouts/MainTemplate.jsp">
      <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/test.jsp"/>
 </definition> 
</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: thanks, but my question is there way we can do virtual directory mapping for the jsps. So that the jsps won't be in the WAR. For example, in weblogic we can do it by adding this entry to weblogic.xml <br/>                <virtual-directory-mapping>
        <local-path>/home/babub/webdev/weblogic10/htdocs</local-path>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*</url-pattern>
    </virtual-directory-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a challenge in giving a fix in jsp when it is put inside WEB-INF in tomcat. Please replace the jsp and edit the jsp within WEB-INF folder of the exploded directory. say for example, if i deploy test.war in tomcat, then tomcat will extract the test.war into test directory inside webapps folder during startup. now, I want to edit the login.jsp in test webapp, i will just make the corrections in login.jsp in WEB-INF folder of test directory (i.e. the extracted folder) not in test.war. that's all

Comment: this is fine for the small application that too at local env. If I'm having some GB's of jsp code and that I can't bind with the WAR file.

Comment: Please edit the server.xml to change the appBase attribute of the Host element to point to the directory where JSP files are stored.you have to configure mod jk connector to fetch the jsp files.Please ensure that tomcat is restarted